# Labelling non-leaf edges in TikZ tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

In a tree made with TikZ, I would like to label edges of the tree.  I saw examples here on StackExchange of using `edge from parent node{label}`, but this only seems to work for the very last edge of the tree, leading down to the leaves.  Here's an example of what I mean (code below the pictures).

First I create my tree in TikZ and label an edge with `edge from parent node{...}`, and this works fine for the edge connecting to a leaf:

[image: Labeling an edge]

However, if I try to do the same thing to label the edge between `B` and `BB`, the following happens:

[image: Label didn't work]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    edge from parent/.style={draw}]
  \node{$\bullet$}
  child {node {\texttt{B}} 
    child {node{\texttt{BB}}
      child {node{\texttt{BBB}} edge from parent node[left]{$\frac{3}{4}$}}
      child {node{\texttt{BBG}}}
    }
    child {node{\texttt{BG}}
      child {node{\texttt{BGB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{BGG}}}
    }
  }
  child {node {\texttt{G}}
    child {node{\texttt{GB}}
      child {node{\texttt{GBB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{GBG}}}
    }
    child {node{\texttt{GG}}
      child {node{\texttt{GGB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{GGG}}}
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    edge from parent/.style={draw}]
  \node{$\bullet$}
  child {node {\texttt{B}} 
    child {node{\texttt{BB}} edge from parent node[left]{$\frac{2}{3}$}
      child {node{\texttt{BBB}} edge from parent node[left]{$\frac{3}{4}$}}
      child {node{\texttt{BBG}}}
    }
    child {node{\texttt{BG}}
      child {node{\texttt{BGB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{BGG}}}
    }
  }
  child {node {\texttt{G}}
    child {node{\texttt{GB}}
      child {node{\texttt{GBB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{GBG}}}
    }
    child {node{\texttt{GG}}
      child {node{\texttt{GGB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{GGG}}}
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `edge from parent node` must be added after all of the child nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    edge from parent/.style={draw}]
  \node{$\bullet$}
  child {node {\texttt{B}} 
    child {node{\texttt{BB}}
      child {node{\texttt{BBB}}
        edge from parent node[left]{$\frac{3}{4}$}
      }
      child {node{\texttt{BBG}}}
      edge from parent node[left,xshift=-4pt]{$\frac{2}{3}$}%<- moved
    }
    child {node{\texttt{BG}}
      child {node{\texttt{BGB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{BGG}}}
    }
  }
  child {node {\texttt{G}}
    child {node{\texttt{GB}}
      child {node{\texttt{GBB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{GBG}}}
    }
    child {node{\texttt{GG}}
      child {node{\texttt{GGB}}}
      child {node{\texttt{GGG}}}
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]